# A monocyclic 6 carbon ring with 6 double bonds

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, nomenclature

I would like to know if this molecule has ever been synthesized, if not why not, and what would its IUPAC name be?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several monocyclic $\ce{C6}$ isomers.  Three of them are pictured below

[image]

- A - the compound you've drawn above, cyclohexahexaene
- B - cyclohexatriyne
- C - cyclohexa-2,5-diyne-bis-1,4-ylidene

While all of the carbons in these molecules are (more or less) $\ce{sp}$ hybridized, the molecules are different from one another due to differences in bond lengths and bond angles.  For example, all of the bonds in A are exactly the same length due to symmetry, whereas the triple bonds in B will be shorter than the adjacent single bonds.  Therefore, A-C are isomers, **not** resonance structures.

Ideally the atoms attached to an $\ce{sp}$ hybridized carbon form a linear arrangement (180° bond angle) with the central $\ce{sp}$ carbon, acetylene and the central carbon in allene serve as examples.

[image]

([image source](http://chemistry.tutorvista.com/organic-chemistry/alkyne.html))

[image]

([image source](http://www.organicchemistry.com/cumulated-alkadienes/))

However in the cyclic $\ce{C6}$ compounds A-C, the $\ce{sp}$ hybridized carbons are forced by the ring to deviate from the desired 180° arrangement to something down around 120°.  Therefore, quite a bit of angle strain is incorporated into A-C making them **extremely** strained and unavailable through laboratory preparation to date.

As mentioned above, A-C have different bond lengths and bond angles therefore they are isomers, not resonance structures.  A fascinating question is,

- Do A-C each sit in a potential well, separated from one another by an energy barrier and if so, which one is the most stable (energy minimum)?

or

- Is there another monocyclic species lower in energy than A-C? Perhaps a molecule that could be described by resonance structures A'-C', where the prime denotes that all of the bond lengths and angles have been adjusted and made equal in A, B and C.

Comment: I would opt for A'-B' benzene heksaradical with only small in plane orbital overlap but symmetry and aromaticity intact.

Answer (score 12):

This is a type of [cyclocarbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclocarbon), specifically [Benzotriyne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzotriyne). Processes using it or synthesizing it have been described in [Towards the total synthesis of cyclo[n]carbons and the generation of cyclo[6]carbon](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1996/P1/p19960001535#!divAbstract), among others.

It has not yet been successfully synthesized. Wikipedia states (without citations) that

> Recent investigations have concluded that benzotriyne is unlikely to exist due to the large angle strain.

Answer (score 2):

Not really with six carbon atoms, but with [eighteen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclo(18)carbon). Cyclo[18]carbon, preferred IUPAC name Cyclooctadeca-1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17-nonayne, is predicted to be the minimal stable carbocycle. According to the WP article, it has been synthesized at low temperature by decomposition of an organic precursor[[1]](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.245.4922.1088) and "claimed"  in the solid state[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.aay1914).

**References**

1.
François Diederich; Yves Rubin; Carolyn B. Knobler; Robert L. Whetten; Kenneth E. Schriver; Kendall N. Houk; Yi Li (8 September 1989). "All-Carbon Molecules: Evidence for the Generation of Cyclo[18]carbon from a Stable Organic Precursor". *Science* **245** (4922): 1088–1090. Bibcode:1989Sci...245.1088D.
https://doi.org/10.1126/science.245.4922.1088. PMID 17838807.

2.
Kaiser, Katharina; Scriven, Lorel M.; Schulz, Fabian; Gawel, Przemyslaw; Gross, Leo; Anderson, Harry L. (15 Aug 2019). "An sp-hybridized molecular carbon allotrope, cyclo[18]carbon". *Science* **365** (6459): 1299–1301. arXiv:1908.05904. https://doi.org/10.1126/science.aay1914.